# Is it possible to use destructuring to append?

Tags: javascript

I wonder if I somehow can use destructuring to to append into a list?

E.g.

```
p = [];
q = [];
var obj_1 = {a: 42, b: 52};
var obj_2 = {a: 43, b: 53};
var {p, q} = obj_1;
{p, q} = obj_2;
```

First time it should give me:
p = [ 42 ]
q = [ 52 ]

and then next time

should give me
p = [ 42, 43 ]
q = [ 52, 53 ]

Above example doesn't work. So my question is whether it is possible to do so with destructing. Or if there are some alternative way?

Comment: *"destructuring"* -- *destructing* is something else entirely ;-)

Comment: hehe true, I changed the title ;)

Comment: couldnt you do {p[1],q[1]}=obj_2 ?

Comment: Given that objects are unordered collections, I don't think they'd make anything like this possible.

Comment: @Jonasw: Yeah, that was my first thought too. You can't quite do that, but you can get close. Took a while for me to figure out why I couldn't get it working (needs parens). But it's...awkward, what with needing `p.length` and such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not in a way that's all that useful or effort-saving. You *can* do this:

```
({a:p[p.length], b:q[q.length]} = obj_1);
```

...but... :-)

```js
const p = [];
const q = [];
const obj_1 = {a: 42, b: 52};
const obj_2 = {a: 43, b: 53};
({a:p[p.length], b:q[q.length]} = obj_1);
console.log("p", JSON.stringify(p), "q", JSON.stringify(q));
({a:p[p.length], b:q[q.length]} = obj_2);
console.log("p", JSON.stringify(p), "q", JSON.stringify(q));
```